# import { createApp } from 'vue' randomly starts throwing error

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I was working on my vue3 project without any errors occuring, when all of a sudden after setting up vue-routing this line:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
```

starts throwing this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative
> references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Before it worked just fine and the error did not appear immediately after setting up the routing.
Also for some reason an image can not be found anymore, even though it is still in the same location as before.

> "GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/icon.svg 404 (Not Found)"

Vue + Vite project, set up via yarn.

Looked up the issue, but no other thread worked for me.

Comment: Are you using GIT or other version control? Consider reverting back to the last functioning version and then starting the process of using routing again.

Comment: Unfortunately i did not yet.I tried to simulate an older version which was working previously and routing was not used yet, but the error was thrown there as well

Comment: I get the feeling that vue-router has not been installed/configured correctly and it's causing these other errors as side effects.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens with freshly set up vue + vite projects via terminal. Same errors occurring as described on top. 
How do I check if router is installed and set up correct?